# How to extract typical rows in MXNet?

Tags: mxnet

These are data(Batch size 2) and batch index

```
import mxnet as mx
data=mx.nd.array(range(24)).reshape(2,3,4)
index=mx.nd.array([[0,1],[1,2]])
```

[image]

How to get the selected data? I tried the `Pick` and `take` functions, but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `gather_nd` works

```
mx.nd.gather_nd(data,mx.nd.array([[0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,2]])).reshape(2,2,4)
```